# Is there any way to keep the Payload tab open in Chrome's network inspector?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Am using a graphql endpoint, so to find out what the operation was, I need to see the payload. However, now that said payload is in a new tab, I have to reselect it every time I check another fetch request. Is there any way to have the payload tab selected by default?

Answer (score 0):

This is fixed in Chrome Canary. Tab stays selected